# how to get all notifications when app is in background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, push-notification

I can get the notification by calling didReceiveRemoteNotification , but if the App is running in background and there are 5 notifications, how to get all notifications when App become active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. The data from a notification can only be pushed by clicking the individual notification. More info here: [iOS Push Notification - How to get the notification data when you click on the app icon instead of notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084015/ios-push-notification-how-to-get-the-notification-data-when-you-click-on-the-a?rq=1)