# Push Notifications for iOS while in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

My app is receiving a notification and my problem is that when I received one or more notifications in the background and when i click the app icon to bring me in my app foreground then the notification message(s) doesn't able to display in the foreground it will only works if I click the pop up message in notification center not the icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Push Notification - How to get the notification data when you click on the app icon instead of notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084015/ios-push-notification-how-to-get-the-notification-data-when-you-click-on-the-a)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve??

Comment: @VishalSonawane: fetch the alert message in notification center so that i can save it in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get remote push notification data on launch of app after tapping icon. You can only parse push notification body only on tap of notification alert. 
So if you want to do any MUST NEED operation for such notifications there is only way is to introduce server in between. So you can use any web service for it and this will be called every time your app launches or comes to foreground. Call that API on background and do the needful you want.